# control_dependencies not as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want tensorflow to do the following in `f(...)`

1. get data[index]
2. cache the value
3. return data[index]

But `tf.control_dependencies` doesn't do what I want.

How to fix the control dependency?

Result:

```
cache_ 0.0
x_ 2.0
AssertionError
```

Test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def f(a, cache):
    assign_op = tf.assign(cache, a)
    with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
        return a


def main():
    dtype = np.float32
    data = tf.range(5, dtype=dtype)
    cache = tf.Variable(0, dtype=dtype)
    x = f(data[2], cache)
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        x_ = sess.run(x)
        cache_ = sess.run(cache)
    print("cache_", cache_)
    print("x_", x_)
    assert np.allclose(cache_, x_)


main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `return a` is Python code. You are not creating any TensorFlow ops in the `with` block. You can use [`tf.identity`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/identity) to create an op that will ensure that when `a` is read from `assign_op` will be executed first. Here is the updated code:

```
def f(a, cache):
    assign_op = tf.assign(cache, a)
    with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
        return tf.identity(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would `tf.identity` creates a copy of the `a` array in the memory? If that is the case, can the experimental jit avoid that?

Comment: The input tensor is only copied if the device is different, otherwise it's just a reference (minimal extra memory used).